# strange lambda expression in groupby

Tags: c#, .net

I am taking over some code written by someone who has left my company.
He wrote the following which has me totally confused on how to read/interpret

```
public override IEnumerable<IEnumerable<ChangeContext>> GroupHistory(
        SqlConnection connection, long seqNum, int batchSize)
    {
        var history = GetHistory(connection, seqNum);
        LastSequenceNumber = history.LastSequenceNumber;
        Timestamp = history.Timestamp;
        // grouping by broker and compacting changes

        return history.Changes.OrderBy(c => c.SequenceNumber).GroupBy(c => c.CtbID, (l, c) => c).ToList()
           .Select(group => ConvertChanges(group));
    }
```

what i am confused is the Groupby.
The first part is clear c => c.CtbID - which is a groupby on CtbID.
what i don't understand is - (l, c) => c
this looks like another lambda with 2 params?

Comment: Look at the documentation to see the overloads. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549393.aspx

Answer (score 3):

That is an element selector, taking the id and the group that is grouped by that id. So you end up with a sequence of the groups.

The specific overload is

```
IEnumerable<TResult> GroupBy<TSource, TKey, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    Func<TKey, IEnumerable<TSource>, TResult> resultSelector)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549393.aspx